# How do I show conditional error using C preprocessor during compilation?

Tags: c-preprocessor

I was finding a way to show error to user during pre-processing and found a way. Checkout the answer.

Answer (score 0):

This is just a way to use the **C preprocessor** `#error` directive for showing *errors according to condition during compilation* Like for example:

```
#define A=50
#define B=30
#define MAXSIZE =10 
#if (MAXSIZE!=A-B)
#error "Please check the values. Their subtraction don't match!"
```

I needed a way to show error to users of my library before building so I used above technique. I hope this will help somebody.